# Oracle: Calculate the count() based on the past 6 month interval for each rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, count, distinct

I have the following data (the data is available from 2017 - Present)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE DATE > TO_DATE('01/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')

 Emp_ID         Date            Vehicle_ID        Working_Hours
 1005          01/01/2019         X500               7
 1005          01/02/2019         X500               6
 1005          01/03/2019         X700               7
 1005          01/04/2019         X500               5
 1005          01/05/2019         X700               7
 1005          01/06/2019         X500               7
 1006          01/01/2019         X500               7
 1006          01/02/2019         X500               6
 1006          01/03/2019         X700               7
 1006          01/04/2019         X500               5
 1006          01/05/2019         X700               7
 1006          01/06/2019         X500               7
```

I need to calculate two columns.
LAST_6M_UNIQ_Vehicle_Count ==> Count of Unique Vehicle ID in the last(past) 6 months for that employee
LAST_6M_Vehicle_Count ==>  Count of all vehicle ID for that employee in the Past 6 months
Note: Past 6 month from the date column

Expected output:

```
 Emp_ID         Date            Vehicle_ID        Working_Hours     LAST_6M_UNIQ_Vehicle_Count     LAST_6M_Vehicle_Count
 1005          01/01/2019         X500               7                      6                       66
 1005          01/02/2019         X500               6                      7                       62
 1005          01/03/2019         X700               7                      6                       63
 1005          01/04/2019         X500               5                      7                       67
 1005          01/05/2019         X700               7                      7                       66
 1005          01/06/2019         X500               7                      7                       67
  .               .                .                 .
  .               .                .                 .
  .               .                .                 .
 1005          03/20/2019         X600               6                      12                      75
 1006          01/01/2019         X500               7                      11                      74
 1006          01/02/2019         X500               6                      10                      66
 1006          01/03/2019         X700               7                      11                      72
 1006          01/04/2019         X500               5                      13                      67
 1006          01/05/2019         X700               7                      12                      64
 1006          01/06/2019         X500               7                      12                      63
```

For example, in the first row, the value for LAST_6M_UNIQ_Vehicle_Count is 6 because for the employee id 1005, the unique count of vehicle id between ((01/01/2019) - 6 month)  and 01/01/2019 has 6 different vehicle id in them.

I tried Over and Partition by but the 6 month interval is missing

```
 SELECT t.*, COUNT(DISTINCT t.VEHICLE_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY t.EMP_ID ORDER BY t.DATE) 
        AS LAST_6M_UNIQ_Vehicle_Count
        FROM TABLE1 t
```

I am not able to calculate the values based on 6 month interval for each rows.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle doesn't like `COUNT( DISTINCT ... ) OVER ( ... )` when used in a windowed analytic function with a range and will raise an `ORA-30487: ORDER BY not allowed here` exception (otherwise, that would be the solution). It will work without the `DISTINCT` keyword but not with it.

Instead, you can use a correlated sub-query:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       ( SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT vehicle_id )
         FROM   table_name c
         WHERE  c.emp_id = t.emp_id
         AND    c."DATE" <= t."DATE"
         AND    ADD_MONTHS( t."DATE", -6 ) <= c."DATE"
       ) AS last_6m_uniq_vehicle_count,
       COUNT(t.vehicle_id) OVER (
         PARTITION BY t.emp_id 
         ORDER     BY t."DATE"
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '6' MONTH PRECEDING
               AND     CURRENT ROW
      ) AS last_6m_vehicle_count
FROM  table_name t
```

Which for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( vehicle_id, emp_id, "DATE" ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2020-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, DATE '2020-07-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2020-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, DATE '2020-05-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, DATE '2020-04-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, DATE '2020-03-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, DATE '2020-02-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, DATE '2020-01-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, DATE '2020-01-31' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> VEHICLE_ID | EMP_ID | DATE      | LAST_6M_UNIQ_VEHICLE_COUNT | LAST_6M_VEHICLE_COUNT
> ---------: | -----: | :-------- | -------------------------: | --------------------:
>          2 |      1 | 31-JAN-20 |                          2 |                     2
>          3 |      1 | 31-JAN-20 |                          2 |                     2
>          2 |      1 | 29-FEB-20 |                          2 |                     3
>          2 |      1 | 31-MAR-20 |                          2 |                     4
>          2 |      1 | 30-APR-20 |                          2 |                     5
>          2 |      1 | 31-MAY-20 |                          2 |                     6
>          1 |      1 | 30-JUN-20 |                          3 |                     7
>          2 |      1 | 31-JUL-20 |                          3 |                     8
>          1 |      1 | 31-AUG-20 |                          2 |                     7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=adf650321ae10204c01481bc61b26b77)*

Comment: This works perfectly .Thank you very much. I have a question for you. If I need to calculate the total count of same vehicle id (present in that row) for that employee in the last 6 month. How to modify the script below

 ( SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT vehicle_id )
         FROM   table_name c
         WHERE  c.emp_id = t.emp_id
         AND    c."DATE" <= t."DATE"
         AND    ADD_MONTHS( t."DATE", -6 ) <= c."DATE"
       ) AS last_6m_uniq_vehicle_count,

Comment: @Virat Same as for `last_6m_vehicle_count`, just `PARTITION BY emp_id, vehicle_id` rather than only `emp_id`.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this with window functions, and a range frame specification.

Computing the distinct count is a bit tricky: Oracle does not support it directly, but we can proceed in two steps. First perform a window count within employee/vehicle partitions, and then take in account only the first occurence of each vehicle in the employee partition.

So:

```
select vehicle_id, emp_id, "DATE",
    sum(case when flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over(
        partition by emp_id
            order by "DATE"
            range between interval '6' month preceding and current row
    ) as last_6m_uniq_vehicle_count,
    count(*) over (
        partition by emp_id 
        order by "DATE"
        range between interval '6' month preceding and current row
    ) as last_6m_vehicle_count
from (
    select t.*, 
        count(*) over (
            partition by emp_id , vehicle_id
            order by "DATE"
            range between interval '6' month preceding and current row
        ) as flag
    from table_name t
) t
order by "DATE", vehicle_id
```

Comment: I ran the script. It is throwing an error "ORA-30487: ORDER BY not allowed here" 
Do you know why this is happening ?

Comment: The error is throwing only for the Count(Distinct t.vehicle_id). I don't know why the group by is not allowed for that part

Comment: @Virat: ah yes, we can't do this like that (MT0 also explained that in their answer). However, a pure window functions solution is still possible. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

As MTO points out, `count(distinct)` cannot be used as a window function to solve this.

For that reason, I would go for a lateral join:

```
select t.*, l.*
from t cross join lateral
     (select count(*) as last_6m_vehicle_count, count(distinct t.vehicle_id) as last_6m_uniq_vehicle_count
      from t t2
      where t2.emp_id = t.emp_id and
            t2.dte <= t.dte and
            t2.dte > add_months(t.dte, -6)
    ) l;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a0d0e13fb3a7c7518554155668c5af59) is a db<>fiddle.